Movie in which the police oficer chases and jumps from the fence and accidentally fires gun and hits person in a car
I have a weird question; I'm trying to remember a movie, probably form 200x years but all my googling, IMDB checking list of drama and cross story failed... that's the reason I'm here.
Movie have crossing story of couple characters and they all come to one event.
I remember one scene that I like very much.
There was a police officer who chased guy, who had gun and tried jump on a fence and while doing that he accidentally fired his gun and shot the person in the car. 
I think the movie was starting form the end and telling how it's go.
Another scene
A guy was in a car with his girlfriend  (she was visiting some guy before) and he tells her that she fucked this guy. She says "no, how you came up with that idea?"
He tells her because he can taste or smell semen from her
- she ask how did he know how it taste?
and he says "he knows because he kissed her after she give him a blowjob".
That's all I can remember, maybe someone ring a bell?

There is a scene in Chopper where Chopper is in the car with his girlfriend and he says she tastes like wog cock after she has been with a Greek man. This film starts out at a later stage in Chopper's life then goes back to his youth and ends up at the beginning at the end of the film.
Year 2000
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0221073/

I just watch chopper, scene look similar but that's not that movie - sorry.

Good movie thou !

I'm more into "Blessed" kind  - great music!!  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d7ikikJyl1E
